# Can these quadratic constraints be linearized?

Tags: optimization, constraints, linearization

I have the following optimization problem:

$\max s$

$\displaystyle \left (\sum_{n=1}^NA_nx^i_n\right )^2 + (1-y_i)M\geq B\sum_{n=1}^N(x^i_n)^2,\forall i=1,2,\ldots S$

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^Sx^i_n=C_n,\forall n\in \mathcal{N}$

$y_i\geq \dfrac{s-i+1}{S},\forall i=1,2,\ldots S$

$y_i\leq s-i+1,\forall i=1,2,\ldots S$

In this optimization problem, $x^i_n\in \mathbb{R^+}$, $s\in \mathbb{N}$, and $y_i\in \{0,1\}$ are decision variables. I have the following questions:

1. Can the quadratic constraints be linearized to transform the problem into an equivalent linear form?
2. If not, what is the best way to solve the problem for exact (not approximate) optimal solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Is $S$ a set or a real? Sometimes, you say $i\in S$ and sometimes, you put $S$ in equations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. My notation is indeed confusing. It should be i=1,2,..., S. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraints imply that $s\in\{S-1,\dots,2S-1\}$. You can maximize $s$ by performing a bisection search on this set, solving a (convex) quadratically constrained feasibility problem at each stage. If a given $s$ yields an infeasible problem, so do all larger values of $s$.

Comment: Why are the quadratic constraints convex?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Bisection search on $s$ fixes $y$, and the resulting constraints can be omitted (if $y_i=0)$ or rewritten (if $y_i=1$) as a second-order cone constraint $z_{N+1}^2 \ge \sum_{n=1}^N z_n^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. By the way, using your method, do you know any efficient way to find the feasible solutions?

Comment: After eliminating $s$ and $y$, you have a second-order cone problem, and I would recommend using a specialized solver for that, such as the [conic optimization solver in SAS](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_027/casmopt/casmopt_conicsolver_toc.htm).